# Linear mixed effect model that differs by variable factor level

Tags: mixed-model, python, random-effects-model, nonlinear-regression

I have below dataset

```
student_id  school_id   non_verbal  quantitative    spatial   verbal    subject score_level valuation
69044       198        117.0         116.0          112.000000   105.0  26        1          77.0
57589       119        104.0         96.0            101.554674  89.0   16        1           62.0
65452       195        83.0          111.0           84.000000   97.0   15        1           62.0
26203       107        98.0          109.0           107.000000  102.0  11        1             47.0
25501       17         111.0         90.0            113.000000  118.0  27        1              62.0
```

My dependent variable is valuation and I want to build a linear mixed effect model where `school_id` is my random effect. But I want this model to differ by `subject` and `score_level`. I want to build this in python.

Can anyone please suggest how should I do this in python also if any better model than linear mixed effect?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by " want this model to differ by `subject` and `score_level`" ? Do you mean you are interested in the "efffects" of these variables on valuation ?  Also do you have multiple students in schools (the data extract does not show this) ?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple students in each school. I want a model that predicts valuation but it should consider the subject and score_level factors while making a prediction.

Comment: Are you trying to predict each school's average valuation or individual student's valuation? Mixed models are particularly good at predicting the outcome at the higher levels of the data hierarchy.

Comment: I want to predict individual student's  valuation

Comment: Are you using any school-level variables in your model? If not, then you may not need a multilevel model. You could instead add dummy variables for schools, called "fixed effects" or adjust the standard errors for the clustering of students within schools.

Comment: @ErikRuzek, except school_id there is no school_level variable that I was thinking to include in my linear mixed model as a random effect.